# Multiple arguments passed from user input remain as single argument

Tags: python-2.7, multiple-arguments

I am trying to understand the mechanics of passing multiple arguments to a python function. (I am using Python 2.7.9)

I am trying to split multiple user input arguments passed into a function, but they all just get passed in as a single argument of the first value:

```
    def foo(first,*args):
        return args, type(args)

    values = raw_input().split()
    print(foo(values))
```

After saving this to a file and running `python <name of file>.py`, I have this output:

```
    $python testfunction.py 
    1 2 2 4h 5   
    (['1', '2', '2', '4h', '5'], <type 'list'>)
    ((), <type 'tuple'>)
```

But if I call foo directly, inside the script like this:

```
    def foo(first,*args):
        return args, type(args)

    print(foo(1, 2, 3, 4, 5))
```

then I get what I want:

```
    $ python testfunction.py 
    (1, <type 'int'>)
    ((2, 3, 4, 5), <type 'tuple'>)
    None
```

Please why does this happen, and how can I get the second case to happen when I accept user input?

Comment: Show us what you mean by "store the values ... inside of the file" - that's probably relevant.  Are you using a here-document, or what?

Comment: I meant calling the function inside of the script, like `print function_name(1, 2, 4, 5)` at the bottom.

Comment: Thanks, @Sina - I've edited that in for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The return value from `split` is a list:

```
>>> values = '1 2 2 4h 5'.split()
>>> values
['1', '2', '2', '4h', '5']
```

When you call `foo`, you're passing that list as a single argument, so `foo(values)` is the same as `foo(['1', '2', '2', '4h', '5'])`.  That's just one argument.

In order to *apply* the function to a list of arguments, we use a `*` inside the argument list:

```
>>> print foo(*values)
(('2', '2', '4h', '5'), <type 'tuple'>)
```

See [Unpacking Argument Lists](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/controlflow.html#unpacking-argument-lists) in the Python Tutorial.

Answer (score 1):

If multiple values are entered in the same line, you have to take the entire set in a single list in Python. You can split it afterwards by the way.

```
values = raw_input().split()
value1 = values[0]
del values[0]
```

This will give you the desired result

Or if you just want to send it to a function seperately,

```
values = raw_input().split()
myfunc(values[0],values[1:])
```

Comment: This last is incorrect - inside the function `args` will be a list containing a single (list) element, not a list containing several strings directly.  Sina wants to _unpack_ the arguments into the function parameters.